How to generate multi-series bar chart with the legend using 3 column data in excel?
Sample data



Env
Server
Value




Prod
Server1
10


Prod
Server2
12


UAT
Server3
15


UAT
Server4
16



Expected output
I want the chart to show a

differently colored series for Prod and UAT servers.
legend as Prod and UAT with same colors as series. Instead of Server1 and Server3 I want legend to show Prod and UAT respectively. Colors can be anything but should different for different series of data. As I selected data range as Server and Value columns only, legend shows all 4 servers in there.

Below is the altered chart (to represent expected output) where

UAT series (Server3 and 4) are manually colored differently.
Server2 and Server4 are deleted from the legend.


What I tried

Use a Combo chart (insert > recommended charts > all charts > combo > clustered column - line). However, it asks me select at least two series of data. Not sure how to do so as I have only Value column as series data source.
Add a new series (right click chart > select data > Legend Entries (Series) > Add. But this did not work.


Format the data with each series in a separate column.
You can use this formula if you have M365:
=PIVOTBY(C3:C6,B3:B6,D3:D6,SUM,0,0,,0)

Like this:

Create a Stacked Column chart. When you do that it will probably look like this:

Right click the series and hit Select data, then select the series and choose 'Edit'. Configure it like this:

Now add a new series and configure it like this:

Change the Horizontal axis (category) labels like this:

Finally add the legend:

EDIT:
It works with more than 2 series, you just need to add them one at a time.


That worked like a charm! Thank you @FlexYourData.

This does not work for more than 2 series. Say if I add "dev" env in sample data and pivot it to have 3 columns "prod", "uat" and "dev". Any suggestions?

It works for more than 2 series. I edited my answer to show an example. I think the chart setup just gets confused, so you need to start by removing whatever series it adds automatically, then add each column as a series, one by one.

Thanks again. This comment is really valuable.
